# Improved performance, Lighthouse audit,

Tags: performance, nuxt.js, lighthouse, prismic.io

I generated a report using Lighthouse for [nuxt-prismic-showcase](https://nuxt-prismic.surge.sh/)

Here the result :
[lighthouse report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8ePc.png)

I set up lazy loading for images, cut to the right size, use next-gen formats, fix ensure test remains visible during webfont load by adding font-display: swap.

I read this article and set up vue-lazy-hydration to try to get better performance :
https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/how-to-drastically-reduce-estimated-input-latency-and-time-to-interactive-of-ssr-vue-applications/

But this did not bring a significant drop.
What can be done to improve the result for Time to Interactive, First CPU Idle and Max Potential First Input Delay ?

Thank you